# Passing structs by void pointer in C

Tags: memory, pointers, struct, allocation, void

I'm trying to implement an ARM/DSP shared memory communication. The ARM side puts a block of data on the shared memory (let'sa name it array[]) and sends the address and the size of the block to the DSP side which just reads them.
On the DSP side,

```
void * buf //address of block on shared memory
int length //size of block
```

However when I try to read them what i get is actually:

```
buf[0] = length
buf[1] = array[1]
buf[2] = array[2]
buf[3] = array[3]
    :
    :
    :
```

It looks as if the length variable overights the first cell of the array (which is kind of strange) or I am using the void pointer the wrong way. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: can you show proc, where you send this data? How do you send address, length, whats size of the array cell?

Comment: It's hard to describe the process since it's a whole DSP/BIOS LINK implementation that uses a built-in API. The ARM side sends data using a Pool_writeback() function and the address is translated from POOL_translAddr() from one address space to another. What is send to the DSP is the starting address of the block and it's length and they are stored respectively to buf and length. The link seems to work fine (tested for "int buf" ). Is this use of void acceptable? If buf[1] has the correct value and buf[0] has the variable assigned directly after the buf, could that be an error on my C code?

Comment: in youre code "buf[3] = array[0]" it's error (buf[3] = array[2]) or not?

Answer (score 0):

i think, that data structure is:

```
buf[0] = length
buf[1] = array[0]
buf[2] = array[1]
:
buf[length] = array[lenght-1]
```

and you must reserve buf for lenght+1

Comment: If it was about allocating memory then i would probably have problems with the end of the array and not the start right? Buf is supposed to point to the array and not the length variable.
The memory block sent is a struct of 
struct {
    int rows
    int cols
    int array[200]
}datastr 
which has a length of 202 integers. 808 bytes.
And since the address of datastr is stored to buf
shouldn't buf[0] = rows
          buf[1] = cols
          buf[3] = array[0]
          ...
instead of buf[0] = <something irrelevant that overights rows>
           buf[1] = cols 
           ...
?